# check parent node if all child are checked C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a custom tree view inherited from asp.net tree view control. with nth level parent- child relationship. based on some calculation I have checked child node. I want parent node should be checked if all the child node are checked. As I am checking child nodes on based some calculation so I can't use after check event.
can some one provide me C# code for that?

```
    private TreeNode _parentNode;
private void CheckedParent(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
            {
                if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    _parentNode = node;
                    CheckedParent(node.ChildNodes);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool allChildChecked = true
                    foreach (TreeNode childNode in nodeCollection)
                    {
                        if (!childNode.Checked)
                        {
                            allChildChecked = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if (allChildChecked )
            {
                _parentNode.Checked = true;
                _isAllChildChecked = false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method will return `true` if all child nodes are checked; otherwise it will return `false`

```
    private bool AllChildChecked(TreeNode currentNode)
    {
        bool res = true;

        foreach (TreeNode node in currentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            res = node.Checked;
            if (!res) break;

            res = this.AllChildChecked(node);
            if (!res) break;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all, .ChildNodes doesn't even exist and it only runs into errors